# How to clip/shape a progress bar

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

How can I clip/shape a `ProgressBar` indicator using a property in the ViewModel?

I want to add a feedback indicator to a `Slider` control using a `ProgressBar`, where I clip so that only a line of circles are shown.  And since the View is resizeable and the circle diameter is fixed, I want to bind the clipped shape to a property indicating how many circles that are to be shown.

I tried using `VisualBrush`, where I tiled `Elipse` shapes.  But it ended with the individual circles being cut, which didn't look any good.

The circle line here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="PART_FeedbackBar" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                Value="{Binding Path=Value}" 
                Maximum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                         AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}, Path=Maximum}"
                Minimum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                         AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}, Path=Minimum}" 
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Background="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                Foreground="{StaticResource HighlightColor}"
                Height="20">
    <ProgressBar.Clip>
        <!-- What to add here? -->
    </ProgressBar.Clip>
</ProgressBar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution using `ProgressBar.OpacityMask` rather than `ProgressBar.Clip`, since `ProgressBar.OpacityMask` supports `VisualBrush`. This way I was able to tile an `Elipse`, which the `ProgressBar` `Opacity` is set to 0 around.

To get the circle count to adjust to the `ProgressBar` width, I added a `SizeChanged` event handler which calculates the number of `Elipse` shapes.  The `VisualBrush` `Viewport` property is bound to the `Elipse` count property, using a `Converter` to convert the `int` value to a `Rect`.

Result:

[image]

XAML:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="PART_FeedbackBar" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
             SizeChanged="PART_FeedbackBar_SizeChanged"
             Value="{Binding Path=Value}" 
             Maximum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                       AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}, Path=Maximum}"
             Minimum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                       AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}, Path=Minimum}" 
             Orientation="Horizontal"
             BorderThickness="0"
             Foreground="{StaticResource HighlightColor}"
             Background="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
             Height="15"
             Margin="25,10">
    <ProgressBar.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush x:Name="FeedbackBarOpacityMask" TileMode="Tile" 
                     Viewport="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                             AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=FeedbackDotCount, 
                             Converter={converters:IntegerToViewportConverter}}"
                     Stretch="Uniform">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Ellipse Height="1" Width="1" Fill="Black" />
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </ProgressBar.OpacityMask>
</ProgressBar>
```

SizeChanged event handler:

```
private void PART_FeedbackBar_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FeedbackDotCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(e.NewSize.Width / 25);
}
```

Converter:

```
public class IntegerToViewportConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var count = (int)value;
        var viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 1);
        if (count > 0)
        {
            viewport.Width = 1 / (double)count;
        }
        return viewport;       
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```